# Pausing in a html/php form without using sleep()

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to add a Success Message before including a page using a form in php. I have searched for options and scripts to do this and sleep() keeps coming up or a javascript. I tried editing the script to fit into my coding but I can't get it working. This is what I have:

```
VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', 'datetime', '$ref')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if($result){   
                Echo "Registration complete!!!";
                include 'login.php';                
        }
    }else{
```

I of course want the delay to go between the message and the login. Please help... Sleep stops the whole script which doesn't display my message.

Comment: You shouldn't need any sort of timed wait or `sleep()`; simply don't submit the form until the confirmation button of the popup is clicked. Have the form submission button open the popup, then the popup button actually submit it (with something like `form.submit()`).

Comment: In addition to this, `md5()` is [**highly insecure**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) (even with a salt) and [should **NOT** be used for password storage](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908/159932). Instead, you should consider [**`password_hash()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [**`password_verify()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) along with a secure algorithm like `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` or `PASSWORD_ARGON2I`.

Comment: I will definitely look at updating from md5... it's what was used back when I was building sites, thank you. 
I will also look into having it be a 2 action like you have here but I was hoping that it could simply be more of a success message and then continue to the login from there with no further action needed

Comment: Still no ideas? I was really hoping to make this work.